# Calculated column in SQL with IF-ELIF-ELSE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, calculated-columns

I need help on how to calculate this calculated column in SQL-code. I have seen earlier in the forum how you calculate based on adding columns together, or just giving a standard value. But in my case, I would like to add a column that could show different pre-set values based on the values of another column. It is just like a normal IF-ELIF-ELSE-statement.

In my case, I have a database, a table, that logs every change one of the users do in the system. Whenever a change is made, the users employee-number is logged to the table and not the employee's name. Since we spend a lot of time going back to these logs, we spend a lot of time looking up which employer-number belong to who. I would like this to be done directly in the query. I have a list of all the employee-numbers and their corresponding names.

My basic SQL-skill only tell me how to import table/columns and create one, but with the IF-statement I am completely lost, below I have performed some pseudo-code so you might understand what I am looking for. A.Emp_Num is the column with the employee numbers and Emp_Name a created column with 'null' as content.

```
SELECT A.EMP_NUM, A.COLUMN1, A.COLUMN2, 'Null' AS EMP_NAME

FROM LOGGINGTABLE A

IF A.EMP_NUM=='1234' THEN EMP_NAME='MONICA'

ELIF A.EMP_NUM=='5678' THEN EMP_NAME='JOE'
```

Comment: is there any relation between em_num and emp_name ?? or you want to hard code the values for all ? any foriegn key relations ??

Comment: do you have a table of employees with ID and Name as columns?  do a join when you look up the log with a select.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I would like to hard code it. I will most probably need the knowledge in later coding. I have no such table, I have them all in a list-document. And there is no relation between the Emp_Num and Emp_Name except the one I am trying to program above.

Comment: ok then you can hard code it .But keep in mind this is not the right way. if you are doing something like this then you have to maintain a relation between these tables. anyway as your requirement you can write a query for done the same.

Comment: i don't know how many employees are in your table . if it is a huge number then it is very difficult to do the same.if you can then maintain a relation between emp_name and emp_num then in future it is easy to identify

Comment: check my answer and let me know still if you have doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below

Note : Maintain relation between EMP_NAME and EMP_NUM in future it will be usefull.
if the employee count is more then we can't hard code the values like below so maintain relationship between them

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN EMP_NUM =1234 
                     THEN 'MONICA' 
                  WHEN  EMP_NUM =5678
                  then 'JOE' 
                  .
                  .
                  .
             END AS nvarchar(1000)) as EMPNAME,EMP_NUM, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM LOGGINGTABLE
```

OR

```
SELECT 
             CASE 
                  WHEN EMP_NUM =1234 
                     THEN 'MONICA' 
                  WHEN  EMP_NUM =5678
                  then 'JOE' 
                  .
                  .
                  .
              END as EMPNAME,EMP_NUM, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM LOGGINGTABL
```

Suggestion: I suggest you to add a new column named EMP_NAME in your table then save these values in that column and in future when ever you insert EMP_NUM that time insert EMP_NAME too then it will be easy to maintain

Comment: thanks for a good answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work in my SQL. The compiler complains about NVARCHAR saying it is an "Undefined name". Replacing it with just VARCHAR gives error as: 
"A DATA TYPE DEFINITION SPECIFIES AN INVALID LENGTH". 

While using just the "Char" the code works, but instead of returning Joe and Monica it just return "J" and "M". Is there some way I can get to multiple characters?

Comment: sql server which version you are using

Comment: try with varchar(1000) rather than varchar

Comment: happy to help you ...i am not god ..i am a fresher in software industry...stackoverflow is god..god of programming :)

Answer (score 0):

OMG, You have employee table in place? Just join it

```
SELECT A.EMP_NUM, A.COLUMN1, A.COLUMN2, E.EMP_NAME
FROM LOGGINGTABLE A
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEETABLE E on A.EMP_NUM = E.EMP_NUM
```

**EDIT:** In case you have entries which are not mapped to user and you don't want to miss them

```
SELECT A.EMP_NUM, A.COLUMN1, A.COLUMN2, isnull(E.EMP_NAME,'No User Linked') as EMP_NAME
FROM LOGGINGTABLE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEETABLE E on A.EMP_NUM = E.EMP_NUM
```

**EDIT:** If you want to get text-documented employees in table

```
BULK INSERT dbo.temp 
FROM 'c:\temp\file.txt'
WITH 
  (
     ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
  )
```

Then

```
Insert into EMPLOYEETABLE
select LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX(' ', column1+ ' ') - 1),
RIGHT(column1, len(column1)-CHARINDEX(' ', column1+ ' ') - 1)
from dbo.temp
```

You may have to revise it, Let me know any difficulties doing so.

Comment: Hi Pravin! I do not have a table, just a longer text-document list. But if I would have such a table, your code would be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Pravin the problm is there is no filed Named EMP_NAME in his table .only some documents he have. that document explains relation between employee name and employee number so there is only one option for this problem he have to hard code it and save it in to table

Comment: Yes, i know, that's why i edited and provided the query to import list into table.

Comment: yes i agree with you. but questioner does not give any clues about the file and its format if it is a well formatted then we can take the corresponding values. but if not then it is difficult.also there is no clue related to file type. is it possible to take data if the file is pdf format ??

Comment: He did gave clue in his above comment. Also additional help is of no harm, isn't it ?

Comment: yes i did't argue with you ...your answer is perfect .and that is the right way of doing the same...hardcode values are not at all good practice your way is right..i just note down some points thats all brother

Comment: Ok i agree with them.